# Menu appearance on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, user-interface

I have two computers with identical hardware, one at work and one at home.
the one at work makes menus appear like this when hovered over:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BFApeVL.png]

the one at home like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/f4hubJ3.png]

The difference is when you highlight, the first one has no border in the middle and the second one does. What controls this behavior? I've been looking everywhere for it!

Notes:
I tested, it is not app-specific. It is computer-wide in scope.
Both appearance settings on both computers are set to "best appearance".

Comment: Have you tried selecting a different theme?  Would have helepd if you took a screenshot of the samething.